# Touches not being recognized from webView on top of uiview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

Currently I have subclassed webview, and added on top of another uiview. I have tried to debug touches event in subclass of webview, or another class where the webview is being added to uiview, but apparently, non of the touches event gets called, unless i set webview as `[self.webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];` however, after doing this I cannot scroll or get any touch events to work. Any help here will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIWebView` does a really good job of eating touches.. what I've done in this case is use a clear `UIView` to overlay the `UIWebView` (it is also possible to do an underlay if the WebView's `userInteractionEnabled` is off.

As long as your `UIView` and `UIWebView` have the same frames, you should be able to get the touches object from `UIView` and use its coords to do whatever you want to do to your `UIWebView`.

-D

Comment: Doug, just curious how do you underlay webview on uiview?

Comment: Normally, when you use `-addSubview`, the view you are adding gets placed on top. So whichever view you add first will be on the bottom. In addition, there are UIView methods which let you controll z-index arrangement. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html see the "Managing the View Hierarchy" header

Comment: Thanks Doug, I got it working now. really appreciate your help here. :)

Comment: Also, not sure what your implementation is, but it's possible (with subclassing) to capture certain gestures with your UIView overlay, and pass the all other touches the the nextResponder (your UIWebView). Again, not sure what you're even doing. As always, happy coding :]

Comment: I am using Responder chain for other purpose here, plus I have a little complicated scenario of adding views on top of other views, where tableview lay on top of the webview, and if pressed on webview, the tableview should disappear including keyboard.